# iOS prepareforsegue throwing xc_bad

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm using a `prepareForSegue` method,

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "roundSegue" {

        var selectedRound:NSManagedObject = roundList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row] as NSManagedObject

        let SVC: SetupVC = segue.destinationViewController as SetupVC

        SVC.course = selectedRound.valueForKey("course") as String
        SVC.existingRound = selectedRound
    }

}
```

However, it is throwing an error "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION", on the 'if segue.identifier == "roundSegue"' line...any thoughts on why it would be throwing this error?

Comment: I think I've had a similar issue before in Swift where Xcode told me the crash was on the if statement, but it was actually somewhere inside the block. Try commenting out the code inside the if statement, then run it again and see if it crashes. If this works, uncomment it line-by-line until you find the actual crashing line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your segue identifier is nil. If this is the case, you are attempting to unwrap a implicitly unwrapped optional variable that is nil, which would cause a crash. try this instead:

```
if let identifier = segue.identifier {
    if identifier == "roundSegue" {
        // your code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Note - this is the correct answer from @daltonclaybrook. However, `identifier` is non-optional so the compiler won't let you do this. I believe this is an Apple bug - it should be optional and allow this check.

Answer (score 0):

STUPID ME! I had an iboutlet that needed to be deleted. that was it. Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

In the Storyboard interface. Click the segue and open the attributes inspector
[image: set segue identifier]

Set the seque identifier and the bad access should be fixed